# What does "or what have you" mean?

Tags: idioms

Does it literally mean

- or whatever that you have

or

- or whatever it is

I’ve heard it in some context and guessed its meaning to be "etc, etc.", but I’m not entirely sure what it means.

Comment: It means *or whatever (else) you might have*.

Comment: or more loosely,  *anything else you (or anyone else) might **think** of [having]*  (i.e. - *etc., etc.*).

Comment: What does your research tell you?

Comment: so this is not a site with a valid question on English usage? On the StackOverflow website really, if you do enough research, maybe you don't need to ask the question any more, but isn't StackOverflow for people to *do research* and find answers?

Answer (score 3):

Your guess is correct. "And/or what have you" is an informal expression (mainly in British English, I think) that means "and/or similar things".

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/and-what-have-you

> **and what have you**
>
> informal
>
> ​and other similar things:
> *There were a couple of bags full of old records, magazines, and what have you.*